# UIView hide children views when out of bounds

Tags: iphone, uiview, visibility

I have a view, lets say 100x100. And it has set of uiviews as subviews: let say 30x30

If a subview has top-left coordinate: (90,90) - I expect to see only part of this subview. But I still see entire area - even if it is out of parents bounds

The question is how to make uiview to show only those parts of subview, which are in original bounds?

thank you

Comment: Does turning on the clips to bound decrease the performance ? is there any other possible answer for this question?

Answer (score 157, accepted):

Set the parent view's `clipsToBounds` property to `YES`.

Programmatically: `view.clipsToBounds=YES;`

Through interface builder: `Click the view->Attributes Inspector->Check Clip to Bounds`

Answer (score 8):

I think you want to enable "clip subviews" on the parent view.

Answer (score 6):

The documentation says that the `clipsToBounds` property of UIView will clip the drawing to the bounds, or more precisely that the subview can't draw outside of the bounds of the superview.

for more read the SO post

[UIView clipsToBounds property: Does it improve performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/820919/uiview-clipstobounds-property-does-it-improve-performance)

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, from the storyboard, tick the parent UIView's "Clip Subviews" checkbox. This is how it worked for me.