# set UIScrollView Visible area

Tags: ios, uiscrollview

I created a `UIScrollView` inside a `UIView`.  
The problem now is that when I scroll it, it goes all the way up until it is outside the frame. 
Frame:

```
[self.deliveryForm setFrame:CGRectMake(24, 330, 273, 207)];
[self.deliveryForm setContentSize:CGSizeMake(273, 307)];
```

[image]

I do not want this: 
[image]

What shall I do to fix this? 
Thank you very much!

Comment: you have work with 2 method,one add the all variable into the UIScrollview inside the UIView, anotherthing no need of UIScrollView, U can diretly scrollup and down the particular fields

Comment: u need tha sample codes

Comment: The reason why I add a scroll view inside a view is that I want the bottom part to be scrollable.

Comment: its k but its shows the irregular view means does not look like good,

Comment: also taken the mismatch view on 3.5" and 4" screen,

Comment: so is there a way to restrict the visible area within the rectangle shown in the first picture?

Comment: If you want to have your `self.deliveryForm` behind all controls try to call after adding all controls `[self.view sendSubviewToBack:self.deliveryForm]`.

Comment: @Sauvage it is at the back but it is still visible.

Comment: write frames of PickUp/Delivery/LanchSpecial control and Street Address textfield

Comment: It will be better to put all controls on the `self.deliveryForm`, set frame `self.deliveryForm` to `self.view.bounds` and `contentSize.height` to `CGRectGetMaxY(yourLastControl.frame) + someOffset`.

Comment: @Sauvage Thank you. Fixed with my own answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fix it!
Thanks for all the help.

Just check `clip subviews` fix everything

[UIView hide children views when out of bounds](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423185/uiview-hide-children-views-when-out-of-bounds)

Answer (score 1):

otherwise simple reduce the height size

```
[self.deliveryForm setFrame:CGRectMake(24, 330, 273, 207)];
[self.deliveryForm setContentSize:CGSizeMake(273, 207)];
```

Comment: So if i make the content size equal to the frame size like you did here, I cannot scroll any more since the content size is equal to the frame size.

Comment: the content size increases also the UIscrollView size increases,

Comment: I see. But still when I scroll the view up, the top part is not disappearing and it covers the segment control view. I do not want this.

Comment: plz delete the old constraints

Comment: otherwise try for link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present

Comment: Yes, that is exactly why I put a scrollview to wrap all the fields. I have successfully implemented that but after the scroll, the fields are overlapping with the seg control view.

Comment: u do another one, add the segment control into the UIscrollview,

Comment: tanx my frind, now how its wks