# UIButton added as subview is away from UIView

Tags: ios, iphone

Tried and searched a lot. Button added as subview is away from view when the frame of superview is small. I dont want it to be appear when frame is small.

```
 UIView *vw = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20 , 100, 200, 30)];
    UIButton *btn = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeSystem];
    [btn setTitle:@"OK" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(20 , 100, 30, 20)];
    [vw sendSubviewToBack:btn];
    [vw addSubview:btn];
    [vw setBackgroundColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    [self.view addSubview:vw];
```

this is my code. It look like this

[image]

Comment: you know the bounds of the superview. test on that to whether you place the button.

Comment: Check First View Hierarchy of UIButton.......It Change in iOS 7

Comment: give [btn setFrame:CGRectMake(20 , 0, 30, 20)];

Comment: Check this 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5423185/uiview-hide-children-views-when-out-of-bounds

You have to clip the subviews

Comment: Button's frame should have y origin 0.

You have to add the btw and then manipulate it.
[vw addSubview:btn];
[vw sendSubviewToBack:btn];

Comment: @svrushal Tnk u.. It works for me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did wrong. Before adding btn to view, you've called `sendSubviewToBack:`. Just rewrite as below.

```
[vw addSubview:btn];//First
[self.view addSubview:vw];//second
[vw sendSubviewToBack:btn];//Third
```

You don't want to appear if it's lie outside superview, use this. `vw.clipsToBounds = YES`

Answer (score 2):

Look on the frame of the UIButton. Its origin.y is 100px. It should be 0, if you want to add it to the vw.